# Bootstrap Modal not showing up in node/express server

Tags: jquery, node.js, bootstrap-modal

I know this question has been beat to death on here, but I can't for the life of me figure out why my modal won't show up. I assume it is an issue with the sourcing of bootstrap, but I have tried so many combinations of script sources and can't get any of them to work. This is an express server project and jquery is sourced via a vendors folder and bootstrap was added via npm.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="./vendors/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="./scripts/client.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
    <title>Weekend To-Do App</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <!-- End Modal -->
    <main role="main">
        <!-- Modal Popup -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="warningModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h1>Warning</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>You are about to delete a task. Please confirm.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
            <!-- end modal -->
        <div>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#warningModal">More info</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: issue is with your jqurey

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced your line

```
<script src="./vendors/jquery.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and modal starts displaying.

Comment: I tried that, but it ends up breaking my $.ajax calls. Seems to be because the slim version removed ajax.

Comment: You are right than don't use slim just use jquery.